# 'FirefoxOptions' does not contain a definition for 'UseLegacyImplementation'

Tags: c#, selenium-firefoxdriver, selenium-edgedriver

I am facing these error when I am trying to nuild my Selenium C# automation framework .NET.
Errors:
'FirefoxOptions' does not contain a definition for 'UseLegacyImplementation'
'EdgeOptions' does not contain a definition for 'UseInPrivateBrowsing'

## Selenium.Webdriver=4.8.2
VS=2019 Version 16.11.26
Let me know if you need further information
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAsem.jpg)

> ## C:\Users\Username\Source\Repos\adept-test-automation\EasyRepro\Microsoft.Dynamics365.UIAutomation.Browser\BrowserOptions.cs(247,17,247,40): error CS0117: 'FirefoxOptions' does not contain a definition for 'UseLegacyImplementation'
> 1>C:\Users\Username\Source\Repos\adept-test-automation\EasyRepro\Microsoft.Dynamics365.UIAutomation.Browser\BrowserOptions.cs(265,17,265,37): error CS0117: 'EdgeOptions' does not contain a definition for 'UseInPrivateBrowsing'
> 1>Done building project "Microsoft.Dynamics365.UIAutomation.Browser.csproj" -- FAILED.

Tried= Upgraded VS, related nuget packages
Expecting: Build Solution to succeed and hopefully to execute test scripts